# Cloud Computing for Mac

Tags: mac, microsoft-virtual-pc

I'm looking to [get into iPhone game development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15048/minimum-hardware-for-iphone-dev), which unfortunately necessitates owning a Mac.

Since I'm currently lacking funds and not 100% sure that this is the way to go, someone suggested to me that maybe I can find an Amazon-EC2-style virtual/online/cloud service that offers Mac (virtual) machines.

Does this service exist? I scoured Google, but couldn't find it. Essentially, I'm looking for something that works like Amazon EC2, but for macs -- you can log in via some remote tool (or via a web interface), and you get your own mac to use.

Answer (score -1):

Apple wouldn't allow it - they make money from hardware, so there's no incentive for them in this kind of service.
Your two options are to use generic PC hardware, see Lifehacker for details or to buy a 2nd hand Mac - a Mac Mini would probably be perfect as you've got the other hardware (screen, Mouse, and keyboard).  Make sure you get a core 2 duo as a minimum otherwise you won't be able to use OS X Lion and the latest dev tools.